# Is there any way to toggle hiding/showing a table column in MudBlazor's MudTable

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a simple MudBlazor MudTable, but looking through the MudBlazor documentation, and after some Googling, I didn't see anything about being able to show/hide columns for a MudTable or if it's even possible. Does anyone know a way?

Here is an example of the table I am using:

```
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudTable Items="@Elements.Take(4)" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Position</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Molar mass</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Position" HideSmall="_hidePosition">@context.Position</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_hidePosition">Hide <b>position</b> when Breakpoint=Xs</MudSwitch>
<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_loading">Show Loading</MudSwitch>
@code { 
    private bool _hidePosition;
    private bool _loading;
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

}
```

I have tried searching for any possible solution and haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: I can't help, but maybe their dedicated Discord community can: https://discord.com/invite/mudblazor

Comment: Have you simply tried `@If(_hidePosition is false)` blocks around the column and header?

Comment: I am honestly confused, I took an example from https://mudblazor.com/components/table#default-table and tried it https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuQcvcFpnVSVAXWH It does not draw a proper table at all, but I can hide a row (which should be a column)...

Comment: "HideSmall" isn't for always hiding the row. Only if it reaches a certain screen size. It's like a media query.

Answer (score 0):

[try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQwvwbppieauJwP](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQwvwbppieauJwP) There you have it, but as @Vischi said, the vertical screen size must be large enough. Try dragging the divider to the left to see the table as in examples.

```
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudTable Items="@Elements.Take(4)" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Nr</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
        @if(!_hidePosition)
        {
            <MudTh>Position</MudTh>
        }
        <MudTh>Molar mass</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Number</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Sign</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        @if(!_hidePosition)
        {
            <MudTd DataLabel="Position" HideSmall="_hidePosition">@context.Position</MudTd>
        }
        <MudTd DataLabel="Molar mass">@context.Molar</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>

<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_hidePosition">Hide <b>position</b> when Breakpoint=Xs</MudSwitch>
<MudSwitch @bind-Checked="_loading">Show Loading</MudSwitch>

@code { 
    private bool _hidePosition;
    private bool _loading;
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>(){new Element(), new Element(), new Element()};

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and show based on screen size you can also try using combinations of d-none and d-xx-table-cell.  This is only hiding the info in the browser and it will still be generated and sent to the browser and visible in browser dev tools etc so not a secure way to do it, just a visual way of styling the table on smaller screens.

This will only show Column 1 up to MD, then Column 1 & 2 up to LG then on LG and wider it will show all 3 columns.

```html
<MudTable>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Column 1</MudTh>
        <MudTh Class="d-none d-md-table-cell">Column 2</MudTh>
        <MudTh Class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">Column 3</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd>@context.Column1</MudTd>
        <MudTd Class="d-none d-md-table-cell">@context.Column2</MudTd>
        <MudTd Class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">@context.Column3</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

See the documentation for more information https://mudblazor.com/utilities/display#visibility